# Unable to locate routes in spring Gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, microservices, api-gateway

have created a very very basic Spring Cloud Gateway from https://start.spring.io/ with the following dependencies

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
  implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
  testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
  }
}

tasks.named('test') {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and my application.yaml is below

```
server:
  port: 9000
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: primary-gateway-users
          uri: http://httpbin.org/
          predicates:
            - Path=uuid
```

have changes nothing in any of the code that is downloaded from https://start.spring.io/ anything i am missing here any configuration should i add other than this.
and it's not working to me.i am getting the below output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path predicate used to redirect to your service is a Spring PathMatcher patterns based on the good old [AntPathMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html)

When you do a request on your gateway the gateway will see the incoming request as `/uuid`.

Your PatchMatcher however is `uuid` and that will not match.

```
PathMatcher springMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();
boolean springMatch = springMatcher.match("uuid", "/uuid");
// will return false
```

If you update your route like this

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: primary-gateway-users
          uri: http://httpbin.org/
          predicates:
            - Path=/uuid
```

your gateway will properly forward the request to http://httpbin.org/